# Add new version of secret via REST

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I would like to add a new version of a secret via GCP REST API.
Sadly the docs are pretty **bland** for REST and not even the URLs are spelled out.

I get a response for:

```
curl -H "authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" 'https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myproject/secrets/foo'
```

but only 404 for:

```
curl -H "authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"payload":{"data":"foo"}}' 'https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myproject/secrets/foo/addVersion'
```

Also tried other permutations.
Can anyone tell me how to construct the REST call to add a new version?

Answer (score 3):

Under the [Adding a secret version](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#add-secret-version) section of the documentation, you can click on the "API" tab and see:

```
$ curl "https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET_ID:addVersion" \
    --request "POST" \
    --header "authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    --header "content-type: application/json" \
    --header "x-goog-user-project: project-id" \
    --data "{\"payload\": {\"data\": \"${SECRET_DATA}\"}}"
```

Where:

- `PROJECT_ID` is your GCP project ID
- `SECRET_ID` is the name of the secret for which you want to add a version
- `SECRET_DATA` is the base64-encoded secret.

Comment: This is true of every sample, including creating secrets, accessing, managing permissions, and deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

If you pop out the API Explorer the start showing you the actual URL. So it is:

`https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myproject/secrets/foo:addVersion`